# "AttributeError: fileno" when attemping to import from pyevolve

Tags: python, pyevolve

I just installed Pyevolve using easy_install and I am getting errors trying to run my first program.  I first tried copy and pasting the source code of the [first example](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/getstarted.html#final-source-code) but this is what I receive when I attempt to run it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/corey/CTest/first_intro.py", line 3, in 
>       from pyevolve import G1DList
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/**init**.py", line 15, in 
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/Consts.py", line 240, in 
>       import Selectors
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/Selectors.py", line 12, in 
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/GPopulation.py", line 11, in 
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/FunctionSlot.py", line 14, in 
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/Util.py", line 20, in 
>   AttributeError: fileno

I am running python 2.6 on Fedora 11 X86_64.

Edit: After looking into it more if I run python from the command line it works but it only fails when I'm running IDLE.

Comment: I'm no expert with Pyevolve, but I have seen similar errors before. They usually tend to be path errors. So <code>import sys</code> and <code>sys.path.append</code> the directory that has these files. Also, do you think you can post line 14 of /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Pyevolve-0.5-py2.6.egg/pyevolve/FunctionSlot.py

Comment: Everything just points to the import statement of the next file.  Its as if it can't find the Util file for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to check out the Development version ? It's near of the RC1, so it is stable right now:
`svn co https://pyevolve.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/pyevolve/trunk pyevolve`

Your problem seems to be the paths, try uncompressing the "egg" file and put the "pyevolve" directory in the site-packages or inside your application directory.